# Pandas: combine columns with different time frequencies

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes: `df_p` and `df_d`.

`df_p` contains 8760 entries, it represents 1 year of records with 1 hour resolution.
`date` is a datetime column, `hy` is the number of the hour (of the year), `profile` is a value

```
                       hy   profile
date                               
1900-01-01 00:00:00     0  0.030908
1900-01-01 01:00:00     1  0.030053
1900-01-01 02:00:00     2  0.043185
1900-01-01 03:00:00     3  0.048040
1900-01-01 04:00:00     4  0.070803
1900-01-01 05:00:00     5  0.070948
...                  ...       ...
1900-12-31 19:00:00  8755  0.058093
1900-12-31 20:00:00  8756  0.030908
1900-12-31 21:00:00  8757  0.030053
1900-12-31 22:00:00  8758  0.043185
1900-12-31 23:00:00  8759  0.048040
```

`df_d` contains 365 entries, it represents 1 year of records with 1 day resolution.
`date` is a datetime column, `HDD` is a value that is valid for the whole day.

```
date           HDD
1900-01-01     9.823750
1900-01-02     7.747917
1900-01-03     5.198750
1900-01-04     7.547500
1900-01-05     9.755000
               ...
1900-12-25     8.549129
1900-12-26     8.245625
1900-12-27     7.641417
1900-12-28     6.176417
1900-12-29     6.368917
1900-12-30     6.443333
1900-12-31     7.224583
```

What I want to do is to create a new column in the `df_p` dataframe which, for each hour of the day, has the respective value of `HDD`.

The following is an example of the desired output:

```
                       hy   profile  HDD
date                               
1900-01-01 00:00:00     0  0.030908  9.823750
1900-01-01 01:00:00     1  0.030053  9.823750
1900-01-01 02:00:00     2  0.043185  9.823750
1900-01-01 03:00:00     3  0.048040  9.823750
1900-01-01 04:00:00     4  0.070803  9.823750
1900-01-01 05:00:00     5  0.070948  9.823750
...                  ...       ...
1900-12-31 19:00:00  8755  0.058093  7.224583
1900-12-31 20:00:00  8756  0.030908  7.224583
1900-12-31 21:00:00  8757  0.030053  7.224583
1900-12-31 22:00:00  8758  0.043185  7.224583
1900-12-31 23:00:00  8759  0.048040  7.224583
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
#if necessary convert to datetimes
df_d['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_d['date'])
df_p.index = pd.to_datetime(df_p.index)

df = pd.merge_asof(df_p, df_d, left_index=True, right_on='date')
print (df)
      hy   profile       date       HDH
0      0  0.030908 1900-01-01  9.823750
0      1  0.030053 1900-01-01  9.823750
0      2  0.043185 1900-01-01  9.823750
0      3  0.048040 1900-01-01  9.823750
0      4  0.070803 1900-01-01  9.823750
0      5  0.070948 1900-01-01  9.823750
11  8755  0.058093 1900-12-31  7.224583
11  8756  0.030908 1900-12-31  7.224583
11  8757  0.030053 1900-12-31  7.224583
11  8758  0.043185 1900-12-31  7.224583
11  8759  0.048040 1900-12-31  7.224583
```

Last for remove column `date` use [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df.drop('date', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you would use [`floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) method from pd.DateTimeIndex and `map`:

```
df_p = pd.DataFrame({'hy':np.arange(365*24), 
                     'profile':np.random.random(365*24)}, 
                     index=pd.date_range('2019-01-01', 
                                         periods=365*24, 
                                         freq='H'))

df_p = df_p.rename_axis('date')

df_d = pd.DataFrame({'HDH': np.random.random(365)*24}, 
                    index=pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=365, freq='D'))

df_p['HDD'] = df_p.index.floor('D').map(df_d['HDH'])
df_p
```

Output:

```
                       hy   profile        HDD
date                                          
2019-01-01 00:00:00     0  0.293717  20.049268
2019-01-01 01:00:00     1  0.573874  20.049268
2019-01-01 02:00:00     2  0.976042  20.049268
2019-01-01 03:00:00     3  0.970939  20.049268
2019-01-01 04:00:00     4  0.178653  20.049268
...                   ...       ...        ...
2019-12-31 19:00:00  8755  0.711155  23.694213
2019-12-31 20:00:00  8756  0.600364  23.694213
2019-12-31 21:00:00  8757  0.708122  23.694213
2019-12-31 22:00:00  8758  0.926454  23.694213
2019-12-31 23:00:00  8759  0.612455  23.694213

[8760 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

#### Extra info per comments below:

```
all(df_p.index.floor('D') == df_p.index.normalize())
True

%timeit df_p.index.floor('D')
```

> 384 µs ± 24.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops
>   each)

```
%timeit df_p.index.normalize()
```

> 530 µs ± 11.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops
>   each)

Comment: nice one, this is where my head went to first instead of`merge_as_of`, I usually do `df_p['HDH'] = df_p.index.normalize().map(df_d['HDH'])`

Comment: @Datanovice yeah... for some reason, I never remember the `normalize` function.   I wonder which is faster.  Normalize or floor?

Comment: I must (embarrassingly) admit I don't really understand the notation above, IIUC `.floor` is better for performance but `normalize` runs quicker per loop ?

Comment: Nah... this just means that over on average .floor ran 384 us with a standard deviation of 24.6 us for 7 runs of 1000 loops.   When normalze averaged a slower with 530 us with tight standard deviation of 11.3 for the same number of runs and loops.